# getting the flags of an IDA name

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk

IDA has the following function [`idc.MakeNameEx`](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/python/idc.py#L631) which accepts multiple `flags` values that set properties about the given name (such as whether it's public, auto-generated, etc).

So far all is good and well, but I would like to do the opposite - *get* those flag values of a name. I'd like to test if a name is public, weak, auto, etc. but I cant seem to find a `idc.NameFlags` method anywhere.

Am I missing something or is this functionality unavailable?

Thanks